# Why does a CSimpleException / CUserException contain the members m_bAutoDelete and m_bReadyForDelete like CException does?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

I was just testing and debugging some code and I struggled over a an exception class that was derived from `CUserException`. `CUserException` is again derived from `CSimpleException` and `CException`.

I know about the usage of `CException::m_bAutoDelete` and `CException::m_bReadyForDelete`.

Now I can see that those both variables `m_bAutoDelete` and `m_bReadyForDelete` are defined in `CSimpleException` again. But they are never used and never initialized. Real strange...

Does anybody know the reason that this variables are redefined in the base class?

[image]

Comment: Those exception types were invented ages before we understood exception handling in C++. The de-facto standard for exception handling in C++ today is: Throw by value, catch by (const) reference. The `m_bAutoDelete` and `m_bReadyForDelete` class members are remnants of the times when throw-by-reference was a potentially correct implementation. I'm guessing that `CSimpleException` is attempting to fix those mistakes from the past, while staying source-level compatible with `CException`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is no solution and not reason.

I compared the current VS-2019 MFC code with the VC-6 MFC Code. the afx.h contains the same unused variables.

So I assume it is a "bug" that what never fixed because of "silly backward compatibility"

Comment: @AlexF When switching to a newer major MFC version it was possible to remove this variables that are really not in use. We had a bunch of version between VC6 and VC2022. Also I assume that this variables are in the MFC CSimpleException class for a much longer time. It is just history...

Comment: `CSimpleException` was introduced in version 3 of MFC. VC6 shipped with version 4.2, so that's the wrong version to look for any hints. As for breaking the ABI with a major version, that's not something you can do lightly. There's merit in being able to mix and match code that was *compiled* with VS2015, 2017, 2019, qne 2022. That's called ABI stability. As for the specific fields being unused, I doubt that is accurate. I'm pretty sure there's at least one path through the macro maze where those are being used, potentially for a platform other than Windows.